# Conditionally render DataSearch component

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering, reactivesearch

I've built a search ui using ReactiveSearch components and it works great! Now I'm trying to figure out how I can conditionally show the [DataSearch component](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/search-components/datasearch.html) that I have in my Navbar based on the route/view that is being displayed.

For example on my homepage. I have a big DataSearch component search form in a jumbotron and I don't need/want the the DataSearch component that also displays in the Navbar.

I've looked at [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) and [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/conditional-rendering-in-react-c6b0e5af381e) but I'm not sure how to implement those in the context of the DataSearch component from ReactiveSearch.

**UPDATE**:

So I've been looking into how I can grab the url from React Router (v4) and it seems I can get it from doing this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
                if (nextProps.location !== this.props.location) {
...
```

So then I thought I could use something like `location !== '/' && DataSearch` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried any of these?

```
{condition && <DataSearchComponent/>}
```

or

```
{condition ? <DataSearchComponent/> : <OtherComponent/>}
```

Comment: Muscala - Thanks for quick response. Been trying different things, still somewhat new to React so trying to understand it all. Quick question -  I will need to set the state on all my components so that the Navbar component will know whether or not to display DataSearch?

Comment: once I figured out the condition part, it worked great.